# redux-saga "all + takeEvery" unit test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I am new in react. Please help me with unit test for redux-saga/effecs.
Lets say I have redux effects for separated feature

```
export function* appEffects() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery(Types.CONFIGURE_LANGUAGE, configureLanguage),
        // other effects for this feature (removed to simplify example)
    ]);
}

function* configureLanguage(action: Actions.ConfigureLanguageAction) {
    const currentLanguage: string = 'en'; // simplified example
    yield put({ type: Types.SET_CURRENT_LANGUAGE, payload: currentLanguage });
}
```

I can test `configureLanguage` directly with following code

```
import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga';


    async function recordSaga(saga: any, initialAction: any) {
        const dispatched: any = [];
        await runSaga(
            { dispatch: (action: any) => dispatched.push(action) },
            saga,
            initialAction
        ).toPromise;
        return dispatched;
    }

    it('should configure language', async () => {
        const action = appActions.service.configureLanguage('en');
        const dispatched = await recordSaga(
            configureLanguage
            action
        );
        expect(dispatched).toEqual([{ type: Types.SET_CURRENT_LANGUAGE, payload: 'en' }]);
    });
```

How can I test `configureLanguage` from `appEffects`? If I try

```
const dispatched = await recordSaga(
            appEffects
            action
        );
```

I receive `dispatched === []`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the `toPromise` method to return the promise - right now you're `await`ing the `toPromise` method itself so `recordSaga` continues before `runSaga` completes and so `dispatched` is still empty when you get to the `expect`.

```
    async function recordSaga(saga: any, initialAction: any) {
        const dispatched: any = [];
        await runSaga(
            { dispatch: (action: any) => dispatched.push(action) },
            saga,
            initialAction
        ).toPromise(); // update here
        return dispatched;
    }
```